# Unable to Run Tensorflow/Keras with GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cudnn

I tried to run Keras with my GPU but got the following error:

> C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\transform_warps.py:84:
>   UserWarning: The default mode, 'constant', will be changed to
>   'reflect' in skimage 0.15.   warn("The default mode, 'constant', will
>   be changed to 'reflect' in " E
>   C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:378]
>
> Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7102 (compatibility version 7100) but
>   source was compiled with 7003 (compatibility version 7000).  If using
>   a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building
>   from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a
>   compatible version specified during compile configuration.
>
> F
>   C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:717]
>   Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(
>   conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms)

I have tensorflow 1.6, CUDA version: Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Comment: You have the wrong version of CUDNN installed

Comment: I just downloaded the right drivers but i still get the error. Is there a way to check if i have the correct version of CUDNN?

Comment: yes there is and you have  already done it. The error message tellsmyu exactly which version of CuDNN you have installed and which version you requre....

Comment: I should get 7.0? I cant find it on Nvidias website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install cuDNN 7.0.5. The file can be downloaded [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn). After clicking Download and agreeing to the terms, the option will be listed.

Comment: My I ask how to find out which version is needed? (Like, how do you know he needs 7.0.5). I downloaded cuda 9.0, then afterwards cudnn 7.1.2 for cuda 9.0, so it is odd to me why it is not compatible.

Comment: Notice that the error received reads:

Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7102 (compatibility version 7100) but source was compiled with 7003 (compatibility version 7000).

This indicates the user had installed cuDNN 7.1 (7100) version but the source library was compiled with cuDNN 7.0  (7000) which led to incompatibility. The latest version of the 7000 series is cuDNN 7.0.5.